# How to manually import the pop animation library

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

My project did not use cocoapod, manual import is always wrong.

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/pop.framework/pop
  Referenced from: /Users/wajiu/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0491E958-0495-435C-8CC3-F42252FBCDD3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/ED44737E-AD08-4D89-937C-8A14AED0CE09/wajiuApp.app/wajiuApp
  Reason: image not found
```

Answer (score 0):

From [pop's GitHub page](https://github.com/facebook/pop#static-library-manual):

> Alternatively, you can add the project to your workspace and adopt the provided configuration files or manually copy the files under the pop subdirectory into your project. If installing manually, ensure the C++ standard library is also linked by including -lc++ to your project linker flags.